# plot a categorial variable based on two other variables

Tags: r

So I have a data.frame which contains the columns date, price and a categorial variable.

```
> head(join)
                 date    e5 near_motorway
1 2019-01-01 05:00:12 1.449             1
2 2019-01-01 05:00:12 1.439             1
3 2019-01-01 05:03:06 1.439             0
4 2019-01-01 05:03:06 1.439             1
5 2019-01-01 05:03:06 1.449             0
6 2019-01-01 05:03:06 1.449             1
```

I want to do draw two lines in one plot based on the categorial variable, with the hour of the date on the x axis and the price on the y axis.

Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = join,
 aes(x = date, y = e5, col = near_motorway, group = near_motorway) +
 geom_line()
```

I am supposing you have date in a date format, e5 as numeric and near_motorway as factor. Also that e5 is price.

And to costume the graph you can play with `scale_y_datetime` and `scale_colour_manual` and with the prefer theme.